# Importing in SOLC to deploy smart contract

Tags: contract-deployment, solc, openzeppelin-contracts

I don't run an Ethereum framework like Truffle and I want to deploy a smart contract using infura node.

The smart contract is very simple:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;  

import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

  /**  
  * @title ACoin is basic ERC20 Token  
  */  
contract ACoin is ERC20, ERC20Detailed, Ownable{  

  uint256 public initialSupply = 100000000000; 
  /**  
  * @dev assign totalSupply to account creating this contract 
  */  
  constructor() public ERC20Detailed("ACoin", "ACO", 7) {  

   _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);

 }


}
```

My compile script should be working fine:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const ACoinpath= path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'ACoin.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(ACoinpath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source, 1).errors);

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':ACoin'];
```

The issue is that solc " doesn't know what import means" and I'm getting this error:

> [ ':3:1: ParserError: Source
>   "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
>   not found: File not supplied initially.\nimport
>   "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";\r\n^--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^\n',   ':4:1: ParserError: Source
>   "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol"
>   not found: File not supplied initially.\nimport
>   "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";\r\n^--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^\n',   ':5:1: ParserError: Source
>   "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol"
>   not found: File not supplied initially.\nimport
>   "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";\r\n^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^\n' ]

I looked into [OpenZeppelin repo](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/README.md#installing-openzeppelin) where I'm told the solution to my problem. An npm install openzeppelin-solidity & import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" later, the problem still persists:

> [ ':3:1: ParserError: Source
>   "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found:
>   File not supplied initially.\nimport
>   "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";\r\n^-------------------------------------------------------------^\n',

Is there anything I can do without using Truffle?

Important to mention: the smart contract provided will work in Remix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`solc` can't get things over a network - it can only import local files, which was your initial error.

I'm assuming your `npm install` step is still leading to failure because the compiler is still looking in the wrong place. (I'd assume the OpenZeppelin stuff has gone into the `node_modules` folder.)

Take a look at how to manually map in localised - i.e. downloaded/cloned - files by passing the relevant options to `solc`.

An example from the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=import%20github#use-in-actual-compilers):

```
> solc github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/=/usr/local/dapp-bin/ source.sol
```

(Remix, being an IDE, has the in-built intelligence to know how to pull files from GitHub prior to the compilation step.)